# Method for finding distinct numbers in an array, and their frequency

Tags: java, arrays, methods, frequency

Help me find the bug in this code, I don't understand why it's not working. I want to display all the unique numbers in an array, together with their frequency (how many times they occur).

```
package myProj;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Freq {

    static boolean isRepeated(int[] temp,int zz){
         int flag=0;
         int l=java.util.Arrays.asList(temp).indexOf(zz);
         for(int p=0;p<l;p++){
            if(temp[p]==zz){
                flag=flag+1;
            }
         }
         if(flag==0){
             return false;
             }
         else{
             return true;
             }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the no of array elements");
        int numOfNumbers = sc.nextInt();

        int arrayOfNumbers[] = new int[numOfNumbers];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the number:");
            arrayOfNumbers[i] =sc.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<numOfNumbers; i++){
            int z=arrayOfNumbers[i];
            if(!(isRepeated(arrayOfNumbers,z))){
                int count=0;
                for(int j=0;j<numOfNumbers;j++){

                    if(arrayOfNumbers[j]==arrayOfNumbers[i]){
                        count=count+1;
                    }
                    else{
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Frequency of "+arrayOfNumbers[i]+"is"+count);
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example expected output for [ 2, 20, 11, 10, 5, 14, 47, 23, 20, 12, 11, 10 ]

- Frequency of 2: 1 Frequency of 20: 2 Frequency of 11: 2 Frequency of
  10: 2 Frequency of 5: 1 Frequency of 14: 1 Frequency of 47: 1
  Frequency of 23: 1 Frequency of 12: 1

Please help rectify my code rather than propose new logic.

Comment: `indexOf()` used in `isRepeated()` returns the first occurrence of the number. Change the method.

Comment: replace indeOf() by lastIndexOf() but why all this for loop ?? What you wan to do?

Comment: Rephrased to put the "ask" before (as well as after) the code, and clarified phrasing + title.

Comment: @boxed__l Thanks, a lot man, I got to know the mistake. Logic wasn't correct in the method isRepeated(). Thanks a lot for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it much more easier:

```
public class Freq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the no of array elements");
        int numOfNumbers = sc.nextInt();

        Integer[] arrayOfNumbers = new Integer[numOfNumbers];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the number:");
            arrayOfNumbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // to remember for what numbers we already count freq
        List<Integer> tmpList = new ArrayList<>(numOfNumbers);

        for (Integer number : arrayOfNumbers) {
            if (!tmpList.contains(number)) {
                tmpList.add(number);
                System.out.println("Frequency of " + number + " is " + Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arrayOfNumbers), number));
            }
        }
    }
}
```